# How to change the Background color of anchor tag on magento?

Tags: javascript, html, magento

i am preparing a Magento Homepage.how to change the background color of anchor tag specific. But I have 5 anchor in single Nav. i want to change the color for 5th Anchor tag.
sorry for poor english
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't add a specific id or class to the link, you can use nth-child:

```
 .containerclass a:nth-child(5) {
     background-color: green;   
 }
```